# How to fix the border gap in Python openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

The bottom border lost in Cell B6

```
thick_border = Side(border_style='thick', color='000000')
thin_border = Side(border_style='thin',color='000000')
no_border = Side(border_style=None)

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=24, max_col=5):
    for cell in row:
        cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color="FFFFFF", end_color="FFFFFF", fill_type="solid") 
        cell.border = Border(bottom=thick_border if cell.row == 6 else no_border)
        if cell.row < 4:
            cell.border = Border(bottom=no_border, right=no_border)
        elif cell.row == 4:
            cell.border = Border(bottom=thick_border)
        elif 4 < cell.row < 22:
            cell.border = Border(bottom=no_border,right=no_border)
        elif cell.row == 23:
            cell.border = Border(top=thick_border,right=no_border)



for row in sheet['C5:D5']:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.column == 2:
            cell.border = Border(right=thick_border)
        else:
            cell.border = Border(right=thin_border )


for row in sheet['A6:E6']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.border = Border(bottom=thick_border if cell.column != 5  else no_border, right=thin_border)
        

sheet['E6'].border = Border(bottom=thick_border)


for row in sheet['B5:B22']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.border = Border(right=thick_border)
```

The border gap occurs in the code

```
for row in sheet['A6:E6']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.border = Border(bottom=thick_border if cell.column != 5  else no_border, right=thin_border)
```

I cannot figure out why there's the gap. The output skip the bottom border in Cell B6. How do I fix the bug?
[image: Excel output]

Comment: You'll need to be more specific, what gap where? In this case a screen shot might help.

Comment: @moken I edited. The gap is in the row 6

Comment: Are you sure no overlap applying border on other method?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the application of the bordering. Are the cells in row 5 & 6 merged (or any cells merged). Have you checked cell B7 (in Format Cells --> Border) to see if the border is applied to the 'top' of that cell? You can add a print statement after `elif cell.row == 7:` like `print(f"Cell {cell.coordinate}")`, which should print each cell as the border is applied to the 'top' . It should print 'Cell A7', 'Cell B7', 'Cell C7', 'Cell D7', 'Cell E7' so you can see if 'Cell B7' appears to get missed.

Comment: @moken I tried and turns out that B7 does not missed.

Comment: I must manually add bottom border in Excel, but I wonder why B6 lose the bottom border?

Comment: You're overwriting B6 in the B5:B22 block and these only have side borders.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the issue is related to the condition 'cell.row == 7'. Unexpected border gaps can be due to the interaction between adjacent cells and their border configurations. When setting borders with different styles, consider the configuration of neighboring cells.

- Start by verifying border configurations of cells above and below the row where cell.row == 7.
- Make sure that the border styles are consistent for adjacent cells.
- You could also use print to identify the unexpected gaps. Something like...

  if cell.row == 7:
  print(f"Before: Row {cell.row}, Column {cell.column}, Border: {cell.border}")
  cell.border = Border(top=thin_border)
  print(f"After: Row {cell.row}, Column {cell.column}, Border: {cell.border}")